# How to repair Central Admin site icons

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration

We're running SharePoint 2013 and had our main app server crash & burn. No problem, I figure - just run the psconfig wizard and bring up the CA site on a secondary app server. Ran the wizard, no problems. Central Admin is now hosted on a new server and comes up fine. Could not run psconfig on the old server since it was dead, so removed it from the farm using the server list on the CA site.

Here's the problem, though: Using the Central Admin desktop icons on any server still tries to bring up the OLD server location. If I change the server name (port remained the same), it will come up after the 2nd or 3rd attempt. For obvious reasons, though, this is annoying.

The desktop shortcuts do not have a hard-coded host name, but instead are this:

> "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\BIN\psconfigui.exe" -cmd showcentraladmin

I'm concerned that there are still references to the old server in the database, otherwise the "showcentraladmin" command should be bringing up the current host instead of the old.

**How can I get the desktop icons to update for the new host?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's behaving properly trying to access the old AppServer. You need to create a new Central Admin on the new AppServer using PowerShell cmdlet [New-SPCentralAdministration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607841.aspx) on your new AppServer.

```
New-SPCentralAdministration -port 2013
```